# How to ask for a decision after an interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I am really interested in working for the particular  company but think that it does not make sense to wait any longer.

A substantial amount of time has passed and I have already other offers.

Is it OK to demand an answer? If yes what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Demand is a strong word. You could just reach out to them and ask. Get in touch with your point of contact and let them know you have other offers on the table. Also think this is a duplicate.. just can't find the exact link right now.

Comment: Side note: looking at the answers, I realized that the OP _might_ have had "ask for" in mind when writing "demand". This is a common mistake in languages where this word means "ask for" (_demander_ in French for instance)

Answer (score 38):

Demanding an answer is never smart. However, providing more information certainly is. You write and say that you have received an offer (or two or however many you have received.) You also say that the company you're writing to is your first choice. Then you ask "Have you made a decision? Can I expect an offer in the next day or two?"

Implied, but not stated, is that if the person says no, or if they say yes and no offer comes in the next day or two, that you will take one of the other offers. You're not saying you'll decline the others if you get one from these people, but you are letting them know the window of getting you is closing. If they care, they'll do something about it.

Alternatively, accept one of your other offers and move on. Not everybody gets back to you. If you do, though, it's polite to email everyone you interviewed with to tell they you're off the market. That will let them move more quickly to their second choice if you were their first, and it will make them think more highly of you (since someone else wanted you) as well.

Answer (score 9):

> *Is it OK to demand an answer?*

It's OK to politely ask for one.

> *If yes what would be the best way to do it?*

"Hi - any decision yet from last month's interview? Or any idea when you'll be letting me know? Thanks!"

Comment: Asking again without new information typically irritates me and I don't think I'm alone in that. Since the OP has new information, it makes perfect sense to provide it.

Comment: @KateGregory, asking for info after hearing nothing for 11 days seems reasonable enough to me, unless they've already told him "we'll get back to you by such-and-such a date".

Answer (score 7):

Keep it cool and clinical. Be straightforward. State bluntly that:

1. You interviewed say last month on such a such a day with so-and-so.
2. You are now looking at several offers, each demanding that you make a decision.
3. You'd like the company to get back to you and if they are still processing you, that time is running short and that decision time for you is approaching.
4. You are writing them because you really like working for them but if their answer is no, that life will go on for you regardless. But you'd rather build a career with them than without them.

You are polite, but you are firm and you are stirring the pot.

Answer (score 1):

"Have you made a decision?"
If no, ask "Is there a time frame?"
If no, "Thank you for the opportunity but at this point I have other offers I need to consider".

Comment: this sounds like declining the job. If you want it, saying "oh ok then I guess I'll go accept one of my other offers, bye" won't get you it. Saying "I have other offers and want one from you" might.

Comment: @KateGregory I was assuming the OP was at a point to take an existing offer

Comment: tbh if they haven't got back to the OP in a 'substantial amount of time' the answer will likely be no anyway.